# How to Create Login Page that Redirects Based on User Roles within active directory

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory

I am currently working on a web application that requires users to login using a single sigin in which is inc-operated into active directory within the active directory login, i want an administrator to have administrative rights to access an admin page within the web based application and the normal user to have access to another page which has read only access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using windows authentication in asp.net with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061795/using-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually control it from the database. For example, You can return a value from based on the user. if value = something, Redirect to 'first' else if value = another, Redirect to 'second' like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with claims-based auth.  I suggest you look at the following:

https://aadguide.azurewebsites.net/claims/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios#claims-in-azure-ad-security-tokens